# Need to hide div when clicked

Tags: jquery, hide

I'm trying to implement an archive functionality into a webpage that will submit something to a web page and then hide the div after it has been submitted. Basically, I'm creating a dynamic ID on a div and and an a tag. Here is my code:

```
<div class="section" id="milestone_<?php echo $milestone['id']; ?>">
  Stuff goes here
    <a href="javascript:void(archiveMilestone(<?php echo $milestone['id']; ?>))" id="archive_milestone_<?php echo $milestone['id']; ?>">(Archive)</a>
</div>

<script>
function archiveMilestone(id)
{
  var dataString = 'remove_milestone='+ id;
    $.post("<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>",dataString);
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('a#archive_milestone_' + id).click(function(){
      $('#milestone_' + id).hide('slow');
      })
    });
}
</script>
```

It seems like it should be straightforward, and the code is getting successfully posted, but the line won't disappear. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="section" id="milestone_<?php echo $milestone['id']; ?>">
  Stuff goes here
   <a href="#" class="btnArchive">Archive</a>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(function(){

 $(".btnArchive").click(function(){
   var item=$(this);
   var itemId=item.parent().attr("id").split('_')[1] 
   $.post("yourserverpage.php",{ remove_milestone : itemId } ,function(){
     item.parent().fadeOut("slow"); 
   });       
 });    
});
```

Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hQkVZ/10/

Comment: @DustinGraham : All thanks to jQuery team. They are the awesome people who made our life better

Comment: Don't I need to strip "milestone_" from the id tag in order to handle it as an integer?

Comment: @user882134: You can do that before sending the post call or do it inyour server page. Initially i used a hard coded id (integer) in my answer.So forgot abt that.

Comment: @user882134: I updated my answer to get the integer part only and send it post

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but this doesn't seem to work for me. It no longer submits the form and doesn't remove the line. In my javascript error console, I see:

Uncaught TypeError: Object function (G){var H=o.map(this,F);if(G&&typeof G=="string"){H=o.multiFilter(G,H)}return this.pushStack(o.unique(H),E,G)} has no method 'attr'
(anonymous function)/customerinfo/customer/115/dashboard/#:453
o.event.handlejquery.js:19
o.event.add.J

Comment: @user882134: My bad, I used the parent function like a property (without ()). Fixed now in my answer and it is working fine now. here is the working sample http://jsfiddle.net/hQkVZ/10/

Answer (score 1):

To start, you shouldn't have `$(document).ready(...` inside of a function.  This should exist in the outermost layer of your Javascript.  Secondly you're using PHP, so the items your wanting to select don't exist until PHP parses them.  Try instead the following to actively bind an event handler to an element:

```
$("#archive_milestone" + id).on("click", function() {
    $("#milestone_" + id).hide("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You also may try `archiveMilestone(<?php echo json_encode($milestone['id']); ?>)` adding the json_encode() as it may need to be escaped.